# Not receiving data from $_POST

Tags: php

I have this

```
<select name="method">
<?php
while($m = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value="' . $m['type'] . '">' . $m['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

And in the html form, in the source, it shows the type and name, and everything works, but when I submit the form, `$_POST['method']` is blank, and var dumped is NULL. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Would be great if you posted the whole form and your php

Comment: it will be blank if no option was selected.

Comment: Is there other inputs in the form? If so, are they submitted successfully? If not, do you have method="POST" in your form element? So many things could be wrong, but when you don't show the whole form, it's hard to pin point exactly what that problem is.

Comment: **Need more "meat"** than that, I'm starving. Show us your full form and more code. Don't give this 'ol Dawg a mere "bone". **Guesswork makes my head hurt, really.**

Comment: @icodebuster Please do not add tags to titles. See [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190) for more information.

Comment: My guess is, you should be using `<select name="method[]">`, that's most likely your problem, without seeing your full codes.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Sorry, my mistake, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Check your PHP version - if it's before 4.1.0 `$_POST` doesn't exist and you will need to use `$HTTP_POST_VARS`

Comment: Then maybe adding `$m = array(); $where = ''; foreach ($_POST['method'] as $meth){ $meth = mysql_real_escape_string($meth); $m[] = "method = '$meth'";`. Could be useful. Again, I have no clue as to what your source code is.

Comment: You have `<select name="method">` - You're not taking into account that "selects" are an **array** and should be used like this `<select name="method[]">` with added `[]`. Try that and get back to me with your results.

Comment: **"Would be great"** if you could maybe interact and give some feedback, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Umm your data isn't inside of a form?

```
<form method="post">
<select name="method">
<?php
while($m = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value="' . $m['type'] . '">' . $m['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="input" action="your path" method="post">
<select name="method">
<?php
  while($m = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value="' . $m['type'] . '">' . $m['name'] . '</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: ^^ how is this constructive Fred?

Comment: @Klinetel Because it's irrelevant. It has nothing to do with the fact that the OP left out the `<form>...</form>` part. It's more likely that the OP did not take into account that his `<select>` must be treated as an **"array"**.